# combine them into one program with a main driver that will call and execute each of the functions

Tags: python

So I had to make 4 different programs with python and the last part of my assignment is to combine them into one program with a main driver that will call and execute each of the functions,

What is the best way of doing this I don't know if you can have the user select what file to import? Or if I have to somehow define each different program?

I'm just kind of lost on what would be the best way of doing this.

Comment: I think your instructor wants you to use modules

Comment: to be honest I'm in a online class and the teacher isn't willing to help much i haven't learned about modules

Comment: I suppose it's not too late to learn now.

Comment: as of right now I'm just trying to get this done so i can start my mid term to be honest im just looking for someone to kind of point me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to do this:

```
from program1 import func1
from program2 import func2
from program3 import func3
from program4 import func4

def call_funcs():
    func1()
    func2()
    func3()
    func4()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    call_funcs()
```

Create a new python file and import each function at the top such as this and in the new file create a new function to call each imported function.  Let me know if this is what you were trying to do.

Edit:  Whoops, I should add that if you have more than one function in each program you can use `from programX import *`

Comment: There is multiple functions in each program i need to have a prompt asking a user what program they wan't to use i just have no clue how to import each program and have a selectable driver

Comment: Is there a way to prompt the user for a number 1-4 and what the user enters imports a different file?

Comment: That wasn't in your question, please update your question to include all of the details.